# Blank screen after trying to log in on GeoServer 2.19.3

Tags: geoserver

One of my devs is complaining about a blank screen after logging in.

I've tried it myself, and all I get is a blank .../geoserver/j_spring_security_check URL with empty information or error messages. It was working before, but I suspect something has been made on the administration side of this server.

No matter what user / password you try, the result is always the same. No obvious error messages on geoserver.log.

Any clues?

```
2023-11-09 15:30:59,865 INFO [geoserver.logging] - Suppressing 
StdOut logging.  If you want to see GeoServer logs, be sure to look in '/opt/geoserver_data_dir/logs/geoserver.log'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,463 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:01,509 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loading catalog...

2023-11-09 15:31:01,564 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'generic'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,565 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,567 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'cite_lakes'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,568 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'green'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,569 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'yellow_line'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,569 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,569 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,570 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,570 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,586 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace sdsda

2023-11-09 15:31:01,605 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sdsda'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,615 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style '105_stl_rt_tramo_vial'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,616 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'SIGRAT'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,621 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'carretera_convencional'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,622 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'alertas_benceno'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,653 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Zona_Influencia_C0'

2023-11-09 15:31:01,653 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Zona_Influencia_NR'

2023-11-09 15:31:02,164 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'bd_cartoteca', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:02,954 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type '_102_parajes', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,166 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'bd_proteccion', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,183 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'zonificacion_zepa_embalse_de_valdecanas', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,185 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'zonificacion_zepa_embalse_de_valdecanas'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,187 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'ais_monfrague', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,188 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'ais_monfrague'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,190 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'subestaciones_electricas', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,191 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'subestaciones_electricas'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,193 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'zepa_spa_extremadura201512', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,193 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'zepa_spa_extremadura201512'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,195 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'limite_monfrague', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,196 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'limite_monfrague'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,199 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'termosolares', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,199 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'termosolares'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,201 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'rt_viaria_sendas', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,202 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'rt_viaria_sendas'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,204 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'datos_ultima_lectura_spida', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,205 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'datos_ultima_lectura_spida'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,207 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'rt_areaffcc_s', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,207 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'rt_areaffcc_s'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,209 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'agrupaciones_voluntarios', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,210 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'agrupaciones_voluntarios'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,212 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'lineas_electricas', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,212 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'lineas_electricas'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,214 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'alertas_por_precipitaciones', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,215 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'alertas_por_precipitaciones'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,219 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'torre_fotovoltaica', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,222 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'torre_fotovoltaica'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,224 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'linea_fotovoltaica', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,224 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'linea_fotovoltaica'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'hb6310', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,227 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'hb6310'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,229 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'rt_viaria_urbano', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,230 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'rt_viaria_urbano'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,231 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'estaciones_saih_con_ultima_lectura', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,232 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'estaciones_saih_con_ultima_lectura'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,233 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'reservas_de_la_biosfera_de_extremadura', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,234 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'reservas_de_la_biosfera_de_extremadura'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,235 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'rt_viaria', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,501 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Colmenas_a_Cero', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,501 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Colmenas_a_Cero'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,503 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Registrados', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,503 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Registrados'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,504 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_NO_Registrados', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,505 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_NO_Registrados'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,506 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Zona_Influencia_C0', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,507 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Apicultura_Asentamientos_Zona_Influencia_C0'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,530 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'Apicultura_NO_Registrados'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,531 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'Apicultura_Colmenas_a_Cero'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,532 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'Apicultura'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,533 WARN [org.geoserver] - Failed to load layer group Apicultura_Asentamientos_Registrados.xml

java.lang.NullPointerException

        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.checkLayerGroupResourceIsInWorkspace(CatalogImpl.java:1017)

        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.checkLayerGroupResourceIsInWorkspace(CatalogImpl.java:989)

        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.validate(CatalogImpl.java:933)

        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.add(CatalogImpl.java:847)

        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.loadLayerGroups(GeoServerLoader.java:1039)

        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.readCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:651)

        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.readCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:449)

        at org.geoserver.config.DefaultGeoServerLoader.loadCatalog(DefaultGeoServerLoader.java:36)

        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.postProcessBeforeInitializationCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:329)

        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.postProcessBeforeInitialization(GeoServerLoader.java:280)

        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoaderProxy.postProcessBeforeInitialization(GeoServerLoaderProxy.java:57)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:413)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:676)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:676)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:676)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1672)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:676)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866)

        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)

        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)

        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)

        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)

        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)

        at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:22)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1457)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1422)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:517)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:157)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:173)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:427)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:785)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:754)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:540)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:146)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:252)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)

2023-11-09 15:31:03,536 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'Apicultura_Registrados'

2023-11-09 15:31:03,538 INFO [org.geoserver] - Read catalog in 2.028 s

2023-11-09 15:31:03,610 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--6e7c2ab6:18bb47e62ba:-8000', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,612 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl--6e7c2ab6:18bb47e62ba:-7fff', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,614 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl--6e7c2ab6:18bb47e62ba:-7ffe', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,620 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl--6e7c2ab6:18bb47e62ba:-7ffd', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,630 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl--2d463c9d:186167dad1a:-7fe0', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,635 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl--2d463c9d:186167dad1a:-7fdf', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,638 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl--2d463c9d:186167dad1a:-7fde', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,641 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--243b5861:18adc01fdd0:-7ff4', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,644 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl-3a2441c0:18acbe2b20b:-5ae4', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,647 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl-3a2441c0:18acbe2b20b:-5ae3', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,649 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-3a2441c0:18acbe2b20b:-5ae2', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,652 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl-5061cc62:188249e8e5c:-4d63', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,654 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl-5061cc62:188249e8e5c:-4d62', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,661 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-5061cc62:188249e8e5c:-4d61', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,663 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl-5061cc62:18824402703:-620c', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,667 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl-5061cc62:18824402703:-620e', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,669 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-5061cc62:18824402703:-620d', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,672 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-69ae819a:186167e87e7:-7ff9', enabled

2023-11-09 15:31:03,687 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory '/opt/geoserver_data_dir/gwc'.

2023-11-09 15:31:03,727 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc

2023-11-09 15:31:03,727 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc

2023-11-09 15:31:03,727 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc

2023-11-09 15:31:03,760 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************

2023-11-09 15:31:03,760 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1.a: No se ha encontrado la declaración del elemento 'gwcConfiguration'.

2023-11-09 15:31:03,760 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.

2023-11-09 15:31:03,760 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************

2023-11-09 15:31:03,793 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc

2023-11-09 15:31:03,794 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc

2023-11-09 15:31:03,833 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog

2023-11-09 15:31:03,833 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers

2023-11-09 15:31:03,833 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers

2023-11-09 15:31:03,893 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loaded 63 tile layers in 59.51 ms

2023-11-09 15:31:03,902 INFO [storage.BlobStoreAggregator] - BlobStoreConfiguration gwc contained no blob store infos.

2023-11-09 15:31:03,907 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************

2023-11-09 15:31:03,907 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to /opt/geoserver_data_dir, using it as the default prefix. ***

2023-11-09 15:31:03,907 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************

2023-11-09 15:31:03,947 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml

2023-11-09 15:31:03,996 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory '/opt/geoserver_data_dir/gwc'.

2023-11-09 15:31:04,005 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory '/opt/geoserver_data_dir/gwc'.

2023-11-09 15:31:04,006 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml

2023-11-09 15:31:04,013 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml

2023-11-09 15:31:04,013 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task

2023-11-09 15:31:04,013 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas.

2023-11-09 15:31:04,014 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 63 layers attached to global quota 500,0 MB

2023-11-09 15:31:04,043 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS

2023-11-09 15:31:04,149 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)

2023-11-09 15:31:04,157 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...

2023-11-09 15:31:04,161 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.

2023-11-09 15:31:04,226 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.

2023-11-09 15:31:04,226 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.

2023-11-09 15:31:05,222 INFO [geoserver.config] - Initiated CatalogTimeStampUpdater

2023-11-09 15:31:05,445 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to set ordering between tiff readers spi

2023-11-09 15:31:07,089 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default

2023-11-09 15:31:07,097 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default

2023-11-09 15:31:07,217 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level

2023-11-09 15:31:07,217 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
```

Comment: your layer or group `Apicultura_Asentamientos_Registrados` is broken, but other than that lt looks fine - so you have probably broken the proxy or CSRF settings - check for errors in the client debugging page

Answer (score 0):

It turns out they were making changes on the webLogin mechanism. Login was broken. I restored geoserver_data_dir/security/config.xml (webLogin snippet) from another environment and it's working again.